# GoogleMaps created a md5 that doesn't work for my app

Tags: android, google-maps

I really hate doing this. I'm going to try to be clear on what I'm doing. I right click my app in eclipse, then go down to android tools > export signed application package. It pops up a window. I see my app name i hit next. keystore selection> create new> C:\AndroidApp\MapKey> create passwords for it hit next. Key creation> create my alias name. lets say mapalias> give it the same password as the keystore. Give it a validity of 1000> insert my name. hit next. destnation and key/certificate check> C:\AndroidApp\MyGoogleMaps.apk > hit finished. After that i open up cmd, I'm on windows 7. I type> keytool -list -v -alias mapalias -keystore C:\AndroidApp\MapKey -storepass mypass -keypass mypass. It generates the md5 code i need. I go to the website to register the md5 code. get the code i need to use on my android:apiKey="ofhsjfjfjmmmmmdnjjffmmf". Run it on the emulator and my phones. I get a grey screen with no map coming up. Theres something I'm missing hear... Please help if you can. Be clear please. I'm a newbe.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".National"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Yorgeys"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Coupons"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>


    <activity 
        android:name=".MainPlant"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".NER"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Store7"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Store13"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".NWR"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Store10"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Store9"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".NNR"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".YIN"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".YWR"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Store35"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Store37"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Store12"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav6"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num6"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav7"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num7"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav13"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num13"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav10"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num10"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav9"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num9"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav8"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num8"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav36"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num36"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav35"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num35"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav37"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num37"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity 
        android:name=".Nav12"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Num12"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Do you have the proper permissions in place? Access net and coarse location?

Comment: the only permissions I have are > <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

Comment: I don't see a coarse location prmission. What does it look like?

Comment: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION?

Comment: Or android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Comment: Thats fine. Coarse location isnt necessary.And you inserted your API key in the XML also?

Comment: yes, example. <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:apiKey="0pn_xvdroofjjgnjnjjdjJJNdmkKKk"
                 android:id="@+id/navView12"
                 android:saveEnabled="true"
                 android:clickable="true"

Comment: Are you sure youve done everything thats listed here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html Do comment if you have modified anything.

Comment: Yea everything runs with a debug md5 code. I have about 10 classes I created with different point on a map in each class with overlays in the same class. I'm really burn out about this. I have no idea what the problem is...

Comment: Im stuck. I hope someone else is able to help you better.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help... Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you added uses-library into application tag in Android Manifest.xml..    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

Comment: Yes, The only thing that I'm not sure of is where to put it if that matters. I have 10 MapViews activitys I'm using. I'm not sure if I insert it in to each one or just have it inserted with the Main Activity in the Manifest.xml...

Comment: I figured out the problem. At lest its what make seance to me. When you first sign your keystore, and you go through all the methods of getting the MD5 code for the keystore, and get the fingerprint for your xml, and place it in your apikey line of code. You have to resign your app with the code inserted. I'm guessing its like a finalize method. I'm going to test another google maps app to see if I'm right... But I did get it to work on my phone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running in the emulator, the app use the debug keystore so you need to use its MD5. 
The apiKey generated using your myMap keystore is for **signed apk** usage, it will work on a phone if you sign the apk or on the emulator if you `adb install` the **signed apk**

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not sure how to use adb. And I deleted the debug keystore by accident trying to figure this out. I've sign my app several times. And deleting them every time I redid it...

Comment: Try recreating a new AVD, in order to get back a debug keystore. Basically, when running under eclipse the app use the debug keystore, when run outside eclipse (on a phone for example), it use the keystore you signed the apk with.

Comment: I figured out the problem. At lest its what make seance to me. When you first sign your keystore, and you go through all the methods of getting the MD5 code for the keystore, and get the fingerprint for your xml, and place it in your apikey line of code. You have to resign your app with the code inserted. I'm guessing its like a finalize method. I'm going to test another google maps app to see if I'm right... But I did get it to work on my phone...